# Android File upload service stops when phone goes to sleep?

Tags: android, android-service

I have made a service to upload a file on server using the asynchronous android task but when my phone goes to sleep, the process stops.When i keep my phone alive the upload code works perfect. What will be the possible solution of it.?

Answer (score 0):

Add a wake lock.

From the Android developer documentation you can do something like:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
Wakelock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Make sure to release the wakelock when you are done like so:

```
wakelock.release();
```

More info here:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: Is there any other way than wake lock? As I am closing the application on upload button and want to show the progress in notification bar.